# Multiple variable declaration, multiple variable assignment, context-sensitive 'in' statement

Tags: programming-languages, parsing, lexer

Lately I've been playing with writing my own programming language, following the excellent [Crafting Interpreters](http://craftinginterpreters.com) book but I've hit something of a snag.

I'd like to extend the parser to accept variable declarations in the form of: `var x,y,z` and to allow for unpacking like `[x,y,z]=[1,2,3]` (noting that jlox doesn't, as yet, support arrays). Finally I'd like to allow for an `in` statement so you can do: `for(x in a)` or to test:

```
var a = {'Larry': 1, 'Curly': 2}
var x = 'Moe'
var b = x in a
print b
```

Output should be `false`. That is: the `in` statement is context-sensitive because it behaves as both an assignment/iterator statement as well as a boolean test. This context-sensitivity is especially problematic because while parsing you'd have to employ some sort of lookback to see if you're in a loop declaration or if you're "just an expression."

Anyway - given jlox - I was wondering if there's something trivial I'm missing to implement the above, or if it's going to be a rather hairy task?

Comment: (1) What exactly is your question here? An open-ended “I was wondering …” is not a focused, answerable question. (2) What kind of parser are you using? The different uses of `x in a` are not ambiguous for any top-down parser, but would be a reduce/reduce conflict for LR.

Comment: The problem seems to me that `for(EXP) BODY` is already valid Lox. In this case you might want to keep `in` just for the check, and use. e.g. `for(x of seq)` for iteration (see JavaScript).

Comment: Also @amon, OP seems to be referring to https://github.com/munificent/craftinginterpreters

Comment: If the parser is hard to write, the language will be hard to write in as well.

Comment: The `in` in `for(x in a)` has to be part of the syntax for the loop, just like the tokens `x` and `a` has to be separate tokens. Otherwise, if it was just a `for(expr)`, you would have a lot of difficulties later actually iterating `a` and making the name `x` available in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to work around it by "segregating" a bit the "id in Expr" construct at the grammar level.

For instance, [Grammophone](http://mdaines.github.io/grammophone/) reports the following as being LL(1), LALR(1), LR(1) :

```
Stmts -> Stmt Stmts | .

Stmt -> for ( id InExpr ) { Stmts } | Expr | Let .

Let -> var id = Expr .

InExpr -> in Expr .

Expr -> id .
```

Which, granted, doesn't completely solve your problem, but gets you closer; if you have chosen to go with a top-down parser, you'll only need it to have more lookahead (ie, than LL(1)) for its "Let" parsing procedure to handle the "var id = id in Expr" case.